# python string replace conditional

Tags: python, string, numpy, pandas

I used a lot of stata but on my new job they won't shell out a license for me and excel is not enough to do a good job.

I want to know how to replace values in a column using a condition (a DataFrame in Pandas).

I've tried:

```
spot['tipo'] = np.where(['programa']=='CLASSIFICADOES' & ['espec']=='', 'N')
```

which gives me

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'list'
```

and tried:

```
spot.ix('programa'=='CLASSIFICADOES' & ['espec']=='', 'tipo') = 'N'
```

Which gives me:

```
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

and:

```
spot.replace(['tipo'],['N']) if spot['programa'] == 'CLASSIFICADOES' & ['espec']==''
```

Which is an invalid syntax. (and this one is much more alike what I would do on stata)
I'm having loads of problems dealing with strings, the numeric parts i can usually find some solution on web.

```
In [79]: spot.dtypes
Out[79]: 
marca        object
data         object
rede         object
tipo         object
programa     object
titulo       object
valor       float64
cm            int64
col           int64
area          int64
descr        object
espec        object
dtype: object
```

Comment: incorrect syntax, should be: `spot['tipo'] = np.where((spot['programa']=='CLASSIFICADOES') & (spot['espec']=='', 'N'))` notice the use of brackets which are required due to operator precedence and you need to index the df itself, what you compared was a list with a single entry which was a string

Comment: Hey Ed, this gives me "ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4692,) (2,) "

Comment: try: `spot['tipo'] = np.where((spot['programa']=='CLASSIFICADOES') & (spot['espec']=='', 'N', spot['tipo']))`, anyway I think my answer shows you another method which should work

Comment: I think I had a typo in my first comment try this: `spot['tipo'] = np.where((spot['programa']=='CLASSIFICADOES') & (spot['espec']==''), 'N')` the closing bracket for the second condition was in the wrong place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you tried has multiple errors:

```
spot['tipo'] = np.where(['programa']=='CLASSIFICADOES' & ['espec']=='', 'N')
```

should be:

```
spot['tipo'] = np.where((spot['programa']=='CLASSIFICADOES') & (spot['espec']==''), 'N', spot['tipo'])
```

notice the use of brackets which are required due to operator precedence and you need to index the df itself, what you compared was a list with a single entry which was a string.

```
spot.ix('programa'=='CLASSIFICADOES' & ['espec']=='', 'tipo') = 'N'
```

should be:

```
spot.ix[(spot['programa']=='CLASSIFICADOES') & (spot['espec']==''), 'tipo'] = 'N'
```

for the same reason as above

Comment: The `spot['tipo'] = np.where((spot['programa']=='CLASSIFICADOES') & (spot['espec']==''), 'N')` seems to be right, but now python tells me np.where should have both x,y or none. i gave only x, and i wish "else  it stays the same value"

the `spot.ix((spot['programa']=='CLASSIFICADOES') & (spot['espec']==''), 'tipo') = 'N'` gives me the same error

Comment: try: `spot['tipo'] = np.where((spot['programa']=='CLASSIFICADOES') & (spot['espec']==''), 'N', spot['tipo'])`

Comment: That's IT Ed! Thank you, well actually it don't give me an error, and doesn't do anything. but if i use another condition besides espec=='' it works flawlessly, so my data on espec, the strings must be messy. but that is a whole other problem. You solved my piece of code. Thank you!

Comment: No worries for your last effort you should consult the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html#pandas.DataFrame.replace and perhaps the [tutorial](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) to get to grips with the fundamentals

Comment: I've read even the "dive into python" but at first is a bit hard to see my own mistakes. also i've dealt with the (spot['espec']==''), i used pandas pandas.isnull(spot['espec']) wich on NaN evaluates to true and then my conditions are met!

Comment: You can also do `spot['espec'].isnull()` which is more readable

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use something like this

```
Var= 'Yes' if fruit == 'Apple' else 'No'
```

In your case i don't fully understand your code, but i think meybe is like this.

```
spot['tipo'] = 'N' if (np.where(['programa']=='CLASSIFICADOES' & ['espec']=='')) else ''
```

Comment: i get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'list'`

Comment: i need to look the hole code for understand what's in this vars. Where "np" come from. And where 'espec' ? and the python operator is "and" my mistake. spot['tipo'] = 'N' if (np.where(['programa']=='CLASSIFICADOES' and ['espec']=='')) else ''

Comment: i imported numpy as np and pandas as pd, the standard thing. 
as i told, i'm using a dataframe in pandas the dataframe = spot
spot['espec'] calls the column named espec 

i got it solved with np.where not using if then else. (np.where already does that)

my solution:

`spot['tipo'] = np.where((spot['programa']=='CLASSIFICADOES') & pd.isnull(spot['espec']), 'N', (spot['tipo']))`